# Encontrar um especifico elemento em uma lista com sub-listas (Python)

Tags: python, lista

Estou aprimorando um código de Pathfindig baseado no A*,

Preciso verificar e modificar um elemento dentro de uma lista com várias sub-listas, mas tenho dúvidas se uso um laço de repetição, ou se já existe alguma função que faça isso, (Que retorne como valor a posição desse elemento na lista).

```
V = 3, 3 # V equivale ao elemento[0] de cada sub-lista.
lista = [[[1,3] 2,1 , 40, 90], [[2,3] 3,2 , 60, 50], [[3,3] 4,2 , 70, 15]...]
```

Como posso por exemplo verificar se V está na lista e se estive, como posso altera-lo. Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Qual a linguagem ? Python ?

Comment: Ops esqueci desse detalhe, sim é python.

Comment: O que seriam esses `[1,3]`, `[2,3]` e `[3,3]`? Não fizeram muito sentido.

Comment: No meu código eles são coordenadas de um mapa(inicialmente de caracteres), onde cada elemento da lista é um posição, com suas informações. (Neste exemplo coloquei valores aleatórios nessas coordenadas pois é apenas um exemplo,)

Comment: Mas `V` é uma tupla ao passo que `[3,3]` é uma lista com dois elementos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se entendi o que você quer fazer, então talvez lhe sirva melhor usar um dicionário com tuplas de posição como chaves:

```
>>> posicoes = {(1, 3): [2, 1, 40, 90], (2, 3): [3, 2, 60, 50]}
>>> posicoes[3, 3] = [4, 2, 70, 15]
>>> print(posicoes)
{(1, 3): [2, 1, 40, 90], (2, 3): [3, 2, 60, 50], (3, 3): [4, 2, 70, 15]}
>>> (3, 3) in posicoes
True
>>> posicoes[3, 3]
[4, 2, 70, 15]
>>> posicoes[3, 3][2] = 80
>>> posicoes[3, 3]
[4, 2, 80, 15]
```

Comment: Com dicionário fico melhor, vlw ae.

Comment: e se por exemplo, eu quiser acessar o 3º elemento desse dicionario, da mesma forma que listas? tipo posição[2] acessa o terceiro elemento... claro que em dicionario não funciona dessa forma, mas tem algum jeito?

Comment: @MarcosVinícius dicionários comuns não garantem manter a ordem de inserção. Se quiser garantir isso, terás que usar um `OrderedDict` (`from collections import OrderedDict` e daí é instanciar e usar normalmente, só instanciando como `posicoes = OrderedDict()`). Daí, dá pra fazer list(posicoes.values())[2] pra acessar o 3o valor elemento (ou `posicoes.items()` pra acessar uma tupla com chave e valor, ou `posicoes.keys()` pra acessar só a chave).

Comment: Cara Muito obrigado!